# ¿cómo poner en bloque, texto e icono dentro de un botón en ionic4, para que uno quede sobre el otro?

Tags: css, ionic4

tengo una lista de botones, las cuales van con icono y texto, el ideal es que el icono esté sobre el texto, pero este no se comporta de acuerdo a la estructura flexbox con la propiedad flex-flow

html

```
<ion-col align-self-center size="4">
    <ion-button size="large" expand="block">
        <div class="icon-dinner large-ico"></div>
        Dine in
    </ion-button>
  </ion-col>
```

css

```
ion-button {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

este es mi resultado actual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola si lo que quieres es que el icono este sobre el texto el *flex-direction* de tu botón debería ser *column*, en tu caso seria:

```
ion-button {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

Prueba a ver si esto soluciona tu problema. Saludos

Comment: ya lo había intentado y no funciona, y en la documentación de ionic4 no salen los botones con iconos, y en la version 3 los iconos aparecen en línea con el texto

Answer (score 0):

la unica solución que pude encontrar, fue el agregar un div dentro del ion-button y a este, incorporar el icono y texto y darle un formato css flexbox

html

```
<ion-button size="large" expand="block" href="/counter">
      <div class="btn-wrap">
        <div class="icon-counter1 large-ico"></div>
        Counter
      </div>
</ion-button>
```

css

```
.btn-wrap {
height: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```